# How to store admin passwords in a way that can be accessed by multiple admins?

Tags: security, password-management

How to store all the admin passwords for routers, servers, desktop computers in the network if they need to be accessible by multiple admins?

There are so many that they can't be memorised and they also change in certain time intervals. Should we keep them in a centralised server or in a specific computer, or should we just simply e-mail them?

Comment: Try an enterprise password manager, like this: https://www.manageengine.com/products/passwordmanagerpro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't email or store them unencrypted.

There are password managers that include sharing features.  One that comes to mind is [LastPass Enterprise](https://lastpass.com/enterprise_overview.php), although I'm sure there are competitors.  If you're allergic to cloud services or spending money (or both), you could perhaps share a [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) database on a (securely nailed down) network share or something along those lines.

Googling "password manager sharing features" or something like that should probably get you started.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using RADIUS against a central server like Active Directory.  This way you can grant access without having to share passwords which in some industries is a no-no.

Most smaller shops probably have an Excel spreadsheet or something simple to keep track of this stuff.

Comment: RADIUS is good, but there are equipment that doesn't support it. Even if we use RADIUS we still have a root/non network account for all computers whose password need to be stored.